# Computing theory: can a single node be a subgraph?

Tags: graphs

Can a single node be considered a subgraph?

For example, if I had this graph, G:

`X`-----`Y`

and I deleted Y, leaving me with the graph

`X`

is this a subgraph (induced) of G?

What about the following argument?

Assume a single node can be considered a graph. Any graph is an induced subgraph of itself. Therefore, a single node graph has a single-node induced subgraph.

Though this is only valid if a single node can be considered a graph.

In computing theory, what is the generally accepted norm?

Answer (score 5):

> What about the following argument?
>
> Assume a single node can be considered a graph. Any graph is an induced subgraph of itself. Therefore, a single node graph has a single-node induced subgraph.
>
> Though this is only valid if a single node can be considered a graph.

That's completely circular. If a single node can be a graph, you can ask about its subgraphs and, sure, every graph is a subgraph of itself. But if a single node can't be a graph, it doesn't make sense to ask about subgraphs of something that isn't a graph.

In general, a single vertex is considered to be a graph, referred to as the "trivial graph".  However, it's something of a special case in that it's often an exception to statements one might wish to make when proving things.  For example, every connected graph contains at least one edge... except for the trivial graph; every graph has a proper subgraph... except for the trivial graph; etc. Because of this, writers often exclude the trivial graph from consideration. So, for example, in the "notation" section of a graph theory paper, you often see a statement such as "Except where stated otherwise, we assume that every graph contains at least one edge".

In this respect, asking whether the trivial graph is a graph is a bit like asking whether zero is a natural number. Some people will jump up and down and insist that it is; some people will jump up and down and insist that it isn't; the best plan is to say that it is or isn't according to what makes your life easiest in any particular situation.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely circular.  I think the OP knows that a graph with a single node is a graph, but is asking whether there's anything special about subgraphs that would mean a graph with one node doesn't count as a subgraph.  The rest is great: +1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an isolated node is usually considered an induced subgraph, as is the graph with no nodes (the empty graph), though sometimes the latter is banished from consideration. If you're not sure whether isolated nodes should be considered induced subgraphs in your particular context, you'll have to tell us more about it.